# How can I change values inside array without a loop Swift

Tags: swift

I have a bool array

For example:

```
 var myBool: [Bool] = [true, true, false, true ,false]
```

and I want to change all the elements from index 1 to index 3

something like this:

```
 myBool[1...3] = true // [true, true, true, true, false]
```

I don't want to use for loop because I have a very big array which is changing fast and the loop is too slow to handle this kind of change.

Answer (score 3):

Any mutable collection responds to `replaceSubrange:with:`

```
var myBool = [true, true, false, true, false]
myBool.replaceSubrange(1...3, with: Array(repeating: true, count: 3))
```

or (credits to MartinR)

```
var myBool = [true, true, false, true, false]
let range = 1...3
myBool.replaceSubrange(range, with: repeatElement(true, count: range.count))
```

Comment: Or `replaceSubrange(1...3, with: repeatElement(true, count: 3))`

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, this is still better.

Comment: With respect to the question (“the loop is too slow”) it would be interesting to know if this is more efficient.

Comment: Hey,
Can I achieve the same thing with a 2D array?

I need to change the rows for example but I dont know how to access only the row to apply the function

     myBool = [ [true, true, false ,true],
                       [false, false, true, true] ]

   myBool.replace.... [row]

Comment: I think so, instead of a single `Bool` the array element is a (sub)array.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to achieve this without iterating through all indices of the array that you want to change, so the minimum complexity of your change will be the same regardless of how you achieve this - even if you don't directly use a loop, the underlying implementation will have to use one.

You can assign values directly to a range of indices in your array, but you need to assign another `ArraySlice`, not a single `Element`.

```
var myBool: [Bool] = [true, true, false, true ,false]
let range = 1...3
myBool[range] = ArraySlice(range.map { _ in true })
```

Bear in mind that the complexity of this will be the same as a for loop. If you are experiencing slowness, that's most probably not because of the for loop.